# Blender 2.8 resize single edge where rest follow proportionally

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to resize a rectangular cubiod, currently 5 meters on it's longest sides and 2 meters on it's shortest sides (as shown in the diagram) I'd like a method that allows me to just set a new length of one edge that proportionally sets the length of the rest of the edges in the cuboid.

So for example: I'd like to be able to type in a new length for one of it's 5 meter edges and make it 2.5 meters. After I do so I need the rest of the edges all to shrink by a half.  The result of this example will make the 4 of the edges 2.5 meters long and the remaining 8 edges 1 meter long.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this is what you want to achieve..
[image]
[image]
select this vertex, then shift+s cursor to selection
[image]
change the pivot point to cursor
[image]
scale down to 0.5, and it should give you this result